# Flutter LongPressDraggable feedback positioned at top left of a container instead of finger press position

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I am new to flutter and a I am trying to create a container that when the user long presses it - a draggable circle shows that the user can move within the boundaries of the container.

I tried many solution, but came to the conclusion that probably the best way to achieve this is to use the `LongPressDraggable` widget on the container, and set the feedback to the circle that the user can drag. The problem is that when I long press the container the circle appears at the top left corner of the container instead of the position of the press. I also tried adding `feedbackOfsset` but it did not work (did not move the feedback position at all, I don't know why).
Also according to the documentation example, this should work as intended and show the feedback on the correct position.

My code:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(239, 223, 224, 1.0),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 230,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: LongPressDraggable<String>(
              feedback: Container(
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 2,
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
                    )
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

To be clear - the wrapper container is necessary because I am adding `Stack` in the child container (just deleted it for this example)

The result: (I painted the wrapper container in purple for the sake of this example)
[image]

Comment: I think i had the same issue before, watch my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773431/flutter-drawing-in-a-container-with-custompainter-and-interactiveviewer-and-not

Comment: It's not exactly the same it takes different parameters. but thank you anyway

Comment: Well, np, i think i have a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to get in the center or where your finger is, we call the property :

[dragAnchorStrategy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable/dragAnchorStrategy.html)  : A strategy that is used by this draggable to get the anchor offset when it is dragged.

Then we only return the **Offset** both with value of 40 because it is the half of 80 (**Container** size), if you like try to put 0,0 or 80,80 to see the difference.

```
 body: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(239, 223, 224, 1.0),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 230,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: LongPressDraggable<int>(
          dragAnchorStrategy:
              (Draggable<Object> _, BuildContext __, Offset ___) =>
                  const Offset(40, 40), // here
          feedback: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2,
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked amazing! also when I use `pointerDragAnchorStrategy` it moves the circle right next to the finger press but not exactly in the middle (not sure why)

Comment: pointerDragAnchorStrategy ? or dragAnchorStrategy ?

Comment: pointerDragAnchorStrategy, beacsue dragAnchorStrategy  doesnt exist - it throws an error